# First Isekai with 'video-game-like' skills?

Tags: history-of, isekai, litrpg

It seems the only Isekai I hear about these days (at least from friends and on this site) are ones where the characters have "video game skills", but reading up on the genre that's not the only theme, and many don't feature that. It's more or an overlap with LitRPG.

I'm going to specifically limit this to 'Skills' - any numeric value assigned to an ability, that is intrinsic instead of assessed. So people being assessed and graded doesn't count. Skills can increase, but not by grading (like going up belts at karate).

Also just assigning levels aren't what I'm after, so no "It's over 9000!" from Dragon Ball.

When did this aspect of Isekai start?

Comment: The oldest I'm seeing on mangaupdates is MÄR, from 2003. I've never read it, so I can't compare it in terms of either moden litrpg manga or even the isekai aspect. Oldest "modern" isekai I'm seeing is Overlord, which was certainly popular enough to be a potential trend setter. I can't remember how the skills specifically worked, but since it took place in a video game it was definitely very video gamey.

Comment: If we're counting anime and/or novels, .hack and Sword Art Online started in 2002.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt do they definitely count as Isekai? They both focus on games that involve Virtual Reality that the user is stuck in, rather than a whole non-game world the character is brought into?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage: That is entirely up to you. And are you looking exclusively for manga? If there's an earlier novel involving someone who knows that they have a 75 Strength after being transported to another world, does that count?

Comment: And if you're willing to include anime, there looks to be a 1990 example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NG_Knight_Ramune_%26_40

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I started off thinking of just Manga, but I removed it from everywhere but the title it seems

Comment: Hmm... first example of in-universe stat awareness would probably be https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/DragonQuestTheAdventureOfDai, but that's not isekai.

Comment: I watched a bit of *NG Knight Ramune & 40* and no stat awareness.

Comment: By isekai, do you require someone moving from our regular everyday world to a real alternate world? I.e. you're ruling out series that are simply set in video game worlds and use stats, or where people are in a VR world that is still technically within the real world (like .hack// or Sword Art Online)?

Comment: I wonder if _Snow Crash_ counts as isekai.

Comment: @Showsni I thought that was implied, but if not I'll add it as an extra requirement

Comment: You're describing a very rare type of work. Few isekai are about video games, and those that are either don't use stat numbers, have a science fiction premise (eg, stuck in VR), or are in a related genre where the setting is clearly supposed to be a video game but there's no isekai framing.

Comment: 1) How video-gamey can the work be? Overlord, for example, is the protagonist explicitly going into the world of video game. But after the isekai it's presented as a functioning world, not a video game. i.e. there are no NPCs that just say "Welcome to Corneria" over and over. (I'm pretty sure that) stuff exists in the world that would not work as a video game. 2) Does reverse isekai count, where the real world becomes game-like? e.g. "Defeating Dungeons With A Skill Board" or "D-Genesis"?

Comment: 3) How important are the numeric values? Consider [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CueFk.jpg) - the protagonist has stats with explicit numbers, a job ("Talent" here), and an explicit list of skills, but no numbers on the skills. I have seen skills with explicit levels, but I feel like just having a skill is more common. E.g. I have the sword skill, ergo I'm good with swords, vs I have the level 3 sword skill.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I decided to add a foreword since I don't think my answer was clear with my intent. I dont think OP's answer is as cut and dry as 'such and such manga was the first isekai with video game skills' I think it's more of a gradient over time. We have 'stuck in a video game', 'in a video game world' and then 'in a fantasy world with video game elements. Where the start of the final one is, is hard to say. My answer isn't that Sword Art Online is the first isekai with video game elements, rather that the start of this trend occurred after SAO came out. It was the catalyst.

Original Post: I'm not sure if this is the first but [*Sword Art Online*](https://swordartonline.fandom.com/wiki/Sword_Art_Online_(series)#Other_publications) by Reki Kawahara was one of the first isekai-like story to heavily include video game elements. If it didn't start it, then it at least popularize the 'trapped in a video game trope'. After that, many isekai took video game elements such as levels, interactable menus and unlockable skills, and just included them as part of a real fantasy world, even if that world had nothing to do with video games.

He wrote the first volume in 2001 and published it as a web novel. It was later adapted into other works such as light novels, manga and anime. The 2012 anime was very popular and led to a large spike of isekai stories in general, both in manga and anime.

While this is not a typical isekai and is just a video game world, it had enough cultural impact that it likely was a catalyst for this trope. Many do consider this an isekai (although the author does not) there are also series like *[Log Horizon](https://log-horizon.fandom.com/wiki/Log_Horizon)* which include people sent to a fantasy world that is *just like* the game they play. Many isekai began blurring these lines so it's hard to find a definitive start to this concept.

Side point but, personally I believe this became a popular trope because its a very explicit way to communicate how strong characters are and a simple way to indicate growth throughout the series.

Comment: Granted the question still isn't super clear about this, but OP isn't looking for stories set in a literal video game world. (See [comment 1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/281238/first-isekai-with-video-game-like-skills/283400#comment775668_281238), [comment 2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/281238/first-isekai-with-video-game-like-skills/283400#comment775726_281238) and replies underneath.) I'm also not sure if they actually have numeric stats shown in the game or not.

Comment: @Laurel Yes I understand that. I was pointing out that because of the popularity of SAO and its isekai-like nature, many isekai to follow it were likely influenced by it and included some of the video game elements they liked from it.

Comment: If we define the term isekai as another world not counting VRMMORPG then Log Horizon is the first isekai with game skills, counting VRMMORPG  then .hack/sign precedes Sword Art Online unless you count the web novel.

Answer (score -1):

How about 1986's "[Super Mario Bros.: The Great Mission to Rescue Princess Peach!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros.:_The_Great_Mission_to_Rescue_Princess_Peach!)" Mario (and his brother Luigi) are shopkeepers. Mario is playing on his Famicom one evening when a princess, Princess Peach, comes out of the game world through his television, and begs Mario to save her, as King Koopa quickly follows her through the TV, kidnaps her and takes her back into the game. The following day a dog is sent from the game's Mushroom Kingdom to bring Mario and Luigi back into the game to save Princess Peach. Over the course of their adventure, Mario collects three Power Ups from the game (the Mushroom, Flower and Star) and is able to use the video game skills they confer; growing in size with the Mushroom:
[image]

Shooting fire with the Flower:
[image]

And invincibility from the Star:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question since it doesn't have "'Skills' - any **numeric value** assigned to an ability, that is intrinsic instead of assessed".

Comment: Almost a perfect troll answer, so +1. However, doesn't actually answer the question, so -1. Overall, no points.